# Стародубский сыр

Tags: согласование

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше сформулировать: "Приходи на Свенскую ярмарку - отведай продукцию "Стародубский сыр" или "...- отведай продукцию компании "Стародубский сыр". Возможно есть ещё какой-то, более приемлемый, вариант? Буду очень благодарна за помощь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Отведай продукцию "Стародубского сыра", или "отведай продукцию компании "Стародубский сыр". В виду специфики названия предприятия второй пример понятнее, так как нет путаницы с названием марки сыра.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Мне кажется, что второй вариант лучше

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал "попробуй".
"Отведать" - хорошее слово для стилизации под старину, но в современных контекстах в прямом значении немного режет слух.

Как-то так:

*Приходи на Свенскую ярмарку, попробуй **стародубский сыр***

Слово "продукция" для рекламного слогана - излишне. 
В отношении написания "Стародубский сыр" - надо разбираться отдельно. Если это название самого сыра, то кавычки не требуются. Если фирменный знак (независимо от юридической значимости), тогда кавычки и заглавная уместны - они как бы заменяют слово "продукция", хотя для рекламного слогана подобные тонкости не важны.